# Syntax error on MySql Function with subquery

Tags: mysql, function

I'm blocked at some point when I'm creating a MySQL function.

This is my current table :

`stats_nba` table ( just few examples of data that I have :

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
|GAME_TIME |   SCORE    | PLAYER_ID |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|2023-11-12|      1     |  444444   |
|2023-11-12|      1     |  111111   |
|2023-11-11|      2     |  111111   |
|2023-11-10|      3     |  111111   |
|2023-11-10|      4     |  444444   |
|2023-11-10|      5     |  555555   |
|2023-11-10|      6     |  666666   | 
  ...          ...         ...
```

This is my SQL function that can't be created :
The goal of that function is to return the average score of the 10 last game of a player ( based on player_id ( called player in the function ) passed in parameter of the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAverage(player VARCHAR)
    RETURNS DOUBLE 
    BEGIN
        RETURN select s.player_id, sum(a.score)/count(a.score) as L10 from stats_nba s join ( select player_id, score from stats_nba where player_id = player order by game_time desc limit 10 ) a on s.player_id = a.player_id;
    END
```

I have this error :

```
syntax error near ') RETURNS DOUBLE
    BEGIN
        RETURN select s.player_id, sum(a.score)/cou' at line 1
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Do you have an explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VARCHAR` requires a length specification, for example `VARCHAR(20)`.

Once you fix that you will also encounter another error in your function. A function in MySQL can return only a single scalar, but your `SELECT` query returns two columns, `player_id` and `L10`.

A procedure can return a result set of multiple rows with multiple columns, but not a function.

---

I tested your function using MySQL 8.2. You must put the subquery in parentheses so it is usable as a scalar value.

Here's what I got to work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAverage(player VARCHAR(100))
    RETURNS DOUBLE 
    READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        RETURN (select sum(a.score)/count(a.score) from stats_nba s join ( select player_id, score from stats_nba where player_id = player order by game_time desc limit 10 ) a on s.player_id = a.player_id);
    END
```

I'm not sure of the purpose of the join in this query. I'll leave the logic of that to you. But at least the syntax is legal and it runs.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I've added `VARCHAR(100)` and I've removed the first column returned by the select `s.player_id`. This select can return now just one column and one row. But I still have the same issue as before :(

Comment: The same error message that you posted above?

Comment: yes, `syntax error near 'select sum(a.score)/count(a.score) as L10 from stats_nba s join ( select player_' at line 4`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ( I saw you edited your response ), maybe I'm using a too old version of MySQL ( currently 5.7.31 but I still have an issue : `syntax error near ' ' at line 5`. Weird.

Comment: I don't know what code you're trying. For what it's worth, here's a dbfiddle that demonstrates it working on MySQL 5.7: https://dbfiddle.uk/MC9QENmF I had to remove the `BEGIN/END` block because the dbfiddle interface doesn't support DELIMITER. That works because the body of the function is just one statement, so it doesn't need a code block.